# Unable to connect Filezilla with Google Compute Engine

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ssh-keys, filezilla

I am trying to connect Filezilla with Google Compute Engine.

I have successfully created an ssh file.

I am unable to get the username and password.

This is the screenshot attached. 
[image]

**Update**

2nd screenshot 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this article?

https://www.onepagezen.com/google-cloud-ftp-filezilla-quick-start/

Comment: I was following this tutorial but I wasn't using Putty so that's where I am getting stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that you followed the recipe in the article found here:

https://www.onepagezen.com/google-cloud-ftp-filezilla-quick-start/

but instead of using putty, you used some other tool to generate the keys.  In my test, I used `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.  This resulted in two files.  One I called `key` and one I called `key.pub`.  The file called `key` is your private key and possession of it validates that you are who you claim to be.

Next, in my Compute Engine, I defined an SSH key to that compute engine.  I pasted in the `key.pub` public file.  At the conclusion, I was presented with a "name" and the key.

[image]

Take note of the name associated with the key.

Now in Filezilla, I pasted in the private key content in the Edit > Settings > Connection > SFTP as described in the original article.

Finally, I was able to access my files from my Filezilla client using `sftp://[IP_ADDRESS]` and using the name (kolban in this example) as the userid.  No explicit password is needed as we have already told Filezilla about the keys associated with my environment.

Comment: thank you for the help, however, this is now the error I am receiving. What am I missing? Please see the new screenshot I have attached.

Comment: In your update .... did you specify the userid in Filezilla that matches the entry seen in SSH keys?

Comment: How do I do that, I added it in the settings and linked the private file, is that the correct way?

Comment: I created a public/private key pair.  For the compute engine, I edited its settings and added an SSH key and supplied the public key.  This then showed me a "name" that I could then use as the user name / userid in FileZilla.  In the FileZilla settings, I imported the private key.  Now when I use filezilla with sftp against the compute engine public address, it works.

Comment: The username is still challenging, how do I add the user? Or how do I know which users have been allowed?

Comment: Maybe create a chatroom or provide some public mechanism for contacting you and maybe we can do a screen share?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200201/discussion-between-kolban-and-dos).

Comment: I agree. Waiting for your assistance in chat.